# How can I center my ul li list in css?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<section class="video">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

                        <ul class="footer-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and with my CSS included (in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfLz08vd/1/)) I get the result that the text is aligned to the left... How can I center everything, so the result says:

```
                  Contact  Press  Careers  Business  Careers  Bussiness
```

?
Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tfLz08vd/2/ ? :)

ul - text-align: center;
li - display: inline-block;

Comment: yes, exactly! Idk how to close this question based on your comment, so if you post it as an answer I'll accept it and close it, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center <ul> <li> into div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708054/center-ul-li-into-div)

Comment: @MatejĐaković, good job! Post an answer!

Comment: Since this question comes up first in Google results for people looking how to center a list including bullets, I thought I'd mention this can be accomplished using `ul {text-align: center; list-style-position: inside;}`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tfLz08vd/2/

just add

```
ul {
text-align: center;
}

li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Similar question added few time ago
[How do I get my <.li> centered in my nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829848/how-do-i-get-my-li-centered-in-my-nav)

You simply have to add text-align: center to ul element like this:

```
.footer-nav{
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try replace li {float:left;} by li {display: inline-block;} and put its parent ul {text-align: center;}

Answer (score 0):

Add this into `ul` css style

```
section.video ul {
    margin-top: 30px;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;    
}
```

See jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tfLz08vd/83/