# Make content center

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem. I have a container which is responsive so it will be the width of the browser. Or when the browser is large enough there will be a sidebar displayed next to it.

Inside this div I have about 10  items with the following css:

```
display:block;
width:200px;
height: 200px;
background: tomato;
margin: 10px;
float:left;
```

So they form a grid.

At this point what happens is that when the container div is 440px width for example. They will diplay nicely 2 on each row. But when the width of the container is 600 for example. still 2 are diplayed with a large white area on the left.

Now I want to center them. So the 2  should be centered in the container. I tought I would do this by adding another container warpping the  elements and giving it a margin:auto; But that doesnt work:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kqvcnugs/

So how do I make sure the items are always in the middle?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Use [inline-block instead of float](http://jsfiddle.net/kqvcnugs/3/), with `text-align: center` on the parent `div`. However, [beware of the whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?
http://jsfiddle.net/kqvcnugs/7/

In your case, just set to **a** `display: inline-block;` and **parent div** `text-align: center;`

But short description is:

```
.parent { text-align: center; }
.children { display: inline-block; }
```

Good luck!! :)

Like this: [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829916/how-can-i-center-my-ul-li-list-in-css/30830043#30830043)

Comment: You legend! thanx a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [**CSS3 flexible box layout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

1. `justify-content: center` on the parent container will align it to
   the center horizontally.
2. `flex-wrap: wrap` will make sure the
   blocks wrap to next line instead of resizing.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
div {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: tomato;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `float`, you can use `display:inline-block;` and then give `text-align:center;` to the parent element.

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
div {
   background: red;
   overflow:hidden;
  /* Add text-align:center; */
    text-align: center;
}

a{
    /* Change to display:inline-block; remove float */
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: tomato;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
    <a></a>
    <a></a> 
    <a></a> 
    <a></a> 
    <a></a> 
    <a></a> 
</div>
</body>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/kqvcnugs/4/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
div {
   background: red;
   overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

a{
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: tomato;
    margin: 10px;


}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/kqvcnugs/8/)